# Column level encryption in Bigquery for streaming inserts

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam-io

We have requirement to store data in Bigquery  using dataflow job  which is reading from kafka. In this , we have some few columns which has sensitive data need to be encrypted.

for example.
schema : element(id , name, phone_num)

in this example i want to do streaming insert of these elements with 'phone_num' as encrypted using KMS.

Please suggest me possible way to achieve it

I have tried exploring BigQuerIO , which has table level encryption , is there any way i can encrypt at column level ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @m.k I have checked with GCP technical support team , currently they do not support this feature , but as workaround , you can make use of KMS service , encrypt your column values ( you can have client specific encryption key ) inside the stream/ batch job before inserting into big query.